# Using Google Sheets Dropdown to Change the Cell Background Color NOT Text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like for the user to be able to use a dropdown within a cell to change the background color of a cell based on a pre-set list of 5 colors. They will be inserting their own text in the cell, however.

So is there any way (using Google Apps Script is fine) to have the dropdown list read the 5 colors (yellow, red, purple, etc) and when they select it have the text in the cell remain unchanged and the background color change to what they selected?  The user text can be anything, so I cannot use conditional formatting for this. Thanks!

Comment: I'd put the color selection on a sidebar and just run it on the active cell.  It's very easy to do.

Comment: @Cooper I currently have it set up in a column immediately adjacent to where the user can enter their own text with a drop down where they can select the color. The code then uses their selection to set the final color. This works just fine, however, the feedback I have received is that everyone wants the dropdown to be in the same cell where they can select the color because it would be "less confusing". I'm afraid using a sidebar wouldn't be any less tricky for the more technically challenged users.

Answer (score 2):

**Changing background color of current cell with a dropdown in a side bar.**

You'll need to create a "Options" sheet and then put the colors you want to use.  In the first cell always put something like "Select a Color";

Code.gs:

```
function bgcolorSelectionForActiveCell(color) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().setBackground(color);
}

function getSelectOptions() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Options');
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var options=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    options.push(vA[i][0]);
  }
  return vA;
}

function launchColorSideBar() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq5').setTitle('Color Side Bar');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

aq5.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(vA){
        var select = document.getElementById("sel1");
        select.options.length = 0; 
        for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
          select.options[i] = new Option(vA[i][0],vA[i][0]);
        }
      })
      .getSelectOptions();
    });

    function setBGColor() {
      google.script.run.bgcolorSelectionForActiveCell($('#sel1').val());

    }
    console.log("My Code");
  </script>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <select id="sel1" onChange="setBGColor();"></select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Definitely a method I will consider if there is no solution like what I am looking for.

Comment: The problem with using validation is that the color string will replace the text in the cell.

Comment: Yes, I am hoping to find a way around that. Was hoping there was another way to add a drop down to a cell without using the validation.

Comment: The whole point of validation is providing acceptable choices.

Comment: @hunter21188 There won't be a way to avoid having the validation overwrite the text, your best choices are having them in the separate cell like you did before or using cooper's solution.